# The method get(int) in the type List<Map<String,Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String) - JAVA & SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting this error message:
[image]

I'm using JAVA & SELENIUM and the function is this:

```
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params) throws
    SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password);
            if (params == null) {
            return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler());
      } else {
          return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler(), params);
    }
     } catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     } finally {
    closeConn();
     }
   }
```

Invoking the function:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "45");
```

After that, i got this error on this line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr[117]/td[3]/input")).sendKeys(resultSet.get("sku").toString());
```

> The method get(int) in the type List<Map<String,Object>> is not
> applicable for the arguments (String)

Why? Is it necessary to replace GET METHOD?

Comment: Your result set is a list of maps.  You need an `int` to specify which element of that list you want to return an item from.  Possibly something like `resultSet.get(0).get("sku")` would work for you, but it's hard to say without knowing what your data is.

Comment: You can't get the i'th item in a list by doing `list.get("somestring")`. Plus you need to follow the stack trace to see where your error comes from. Plus your code gives no clue whatsoever about what causes the error.

Comment: Pls post your complete code and some sample data you are trying to retrieve.